# How can I get a form clone variables?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub playbtnclick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles playbutton.Click
    Dim form2clone As New Form2
    form2clone.Tag = selectedpicid
    form2clone.Show()
End Sub


Public Sub labelclick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim lbl As Label = sender

    For Each frm2 As Form2 In 'How can I find specified form2? 
        If frm2.Tag = searchtag Then
            TextBox1.Text = frm2.justvariable & lbl.Tag
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I find specified form2 and get a form clone variables in VB.net?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your form2 in a list, then loop through that list.
E.g.

```
Dim ALForm2 as new list (of Form2)
Dim form2clone As New Form2 
form2clone.Tag = selectedpicid 
form2clone.Show()
ALForm2.Add (form2clone)
```

then you can loop through ALForm2